# UIPickerView Content Not Showing in iOS7

Tags: ios7, uipickerview

After updating to Xcode 5 and updating my app to work with iOS7, the UIPickerView will not display the content of my array and comes up blank.  After putting the following code in, the array will show up in the UIPickerView but will crash after a few spins:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@" ",@" ",@" ",@" ",@" ",@" ",@" ",@" ",@" ",@" ",@" ", nil];
    self.contentArray = array;   
}
```

Here are the UIPickerView delegate methods:

```
    #pragma mark - pickerview methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:      (NSInteger)component {
    return contentArray.count;
}


- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    return [self.contentArray objectAtIndex:row];

}
```

I know this is wrong, but as a newbie developer cannot get it right.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thank you in advance for your input, I've been working on this 3 days and can't move on.

Comment: Can you show your UIPickerView delegate codes? Presumably they use self.contentArray?

Comment: I posted the delegate code and pickerView methods.

Comment: Ok, just for sanity check, you are aware that you are filling self.contentArray with strings of whitespaces, right? What exactly is not showing, can you tell us more? Can you show us the crash log?

Comment: Yes, I understand the strings of whitespace don't make sense, but for some reason they are triggering my contentArray to appear.  Here is the crash log:

Comment: The crash log:    2014-01-10 19:36:56.141 My App[2472:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2eb24e83 0x38e816c7 0x2ea5aff9 0xb3f83 0x3151ca41 0x3151f861 0x317ef29f 0x313db315 0x313836cd 0x31382ef1 0x3174ac25 0x312a9353 0x30f2f943 0x30f2b167 0x30f2aff9 0x30f2aa0d 0x30f2a81f 0x30f7f929 0x33baf76d 0x2f806be5 0x2eae4b81 0x2eaef777 0x2eaef713 0x2eaededf 0x2ea58471 0x2ea58253 0x337922eb

Comment: Update:  When I made the number of blank white spaces equal to the number of rows on my picker the app doesn't crash and functions properly.  I still don't understand why it works and the pickerView rows need a trigger to appear.

Comment: Of course, because the previous crash is because your have more rows than you have data. I don't understand how that is because clearly your `numberOfRowsInComponent` is returning the correct size though. I need more info.

Comment: What's even stranger is that I have 2 arrays: 1 which is a date array of years which has more than 100 objects, and 1 which is defined with 10 objects.  When you pull up the date array only 10 years will show in the pickerView.  The app is now running fine, not even a compilation error, so I'm going to let this issue go for now.